# Date comparison failing

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to compare two date objects when deciding whether to enter a while loop.

I have set a breakpoint and printed both values to the console and they are identical - the while loop is bypassed however.

```
while currentTime + intervalTime <= endTime { }
```

`currentTime` is a Date object, as is `endTime`. `intervalTime` is a TimeInterval. When I used the breakpoint and printed to the console I got the following result. This look like they should be equal but, as I say, the while loop is bypassed.

```
(lldb) print currentTime + intervalTime
(Date) $R8 = 2019-02-04 13:19:05 UTC
(lldb) print endTime
(Date) $R10 = 2019-02-04 13:19:05 UTC
```

Comment: A Date stores fractional seconds as well – try `print((currentTime + intervalTime).timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, endTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)`

Comment: @MartinR Ah you're right! ```currentTime + intervalTime``` has numbers after the decimal point whereas ```endTime``` is a whole number. How would you suggest comparing them?

Comment: Hacky solution but I just subtracted 1 second from ```intervalTime``` to negate the effect of the fractional.

Comment: Another option would be to truncate it to an integer: `while Int(...) <= Int(endTime) { }` – Without more context it is difficult to tell what the “proper” solution in your case is.

Comment: @MartinR that would work too and seems a little more appropriate. Thanks for your help. If you leave an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` represents an absolute point in time, and includes fractional seconds (up to some precision, limited by the precision of `TimeInterval` aka `Double`, and probably other factors).

You can truncate the time interval to integral seconds, or use the proper `Calendar` methods:

```
let date = Date()
let date1 = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .second, for: date)!.start

print(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)  // 571003391.256104
print(date1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) // 571003391.0
```

You can also compare two dates with a “granularity” of whole seconds:

```
if Calendar.current.compare(currentDate, to: endDate, toGranularity: .second) != .orderedAscending { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, great answer.